# Difference between model fields(in django) and serializer fields(in django rest framework)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

As we can validate the values using the conventional model field then why Django REST Framework contains its own serializer fields. I know that serializer fields are used to handle the converting between primitive values and internal datatypes. Except this, is there anything different between them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well there is a `ModelSerializer` that can automatically provide the serializer fields based on your model fields (given the duality you described). A `ModelSerializer` allows you to select which models fields are going to appear as fields in the serializer, thus allowing you to show/hide some fields.

A field in a model, is conventionally tied to a data store (say a column in a database).

A DRF `Serializer` can exist without a Django model too, as it serves to communicate between the API and the client, and its fields can be in many forms that are independent from the model and the backing database, e.g. `ReadOnlyField`, `SerializerMethodField` etc

Answer (score 7):

Model fields are what you keep in your database.
(it answers how you want your data organized)

Serializer fields are what you expose to your clients.
(it answers how you want your data represented)

For `models.ForeignKey(User)` of your model,

you can represent it in your serializer as an `Int` field, or `UserSerializer`(which you will define), or as `http link` that points to the api endpoint for the user. 
You can represent the user with `username`, it's up to how you want to represent it.

With DRF,
You can hide model fields, mark it as read-only/write-only.
You can also add a field that is not mappable to a model field.

Comment: So, We are saying that serializers here just for the sake of response builders ? Model to save them ? separation of concerns ?

Comment: @89n3ur0n it can be used when you are building response, and it also can be used to interpret request and save to model.

Comment: Ok, I see we want to move away from ModelForm and handle everything with serializers , new way of doing the job. Correct ?

Comment: @89n3ur0n you can do that, DRF serializers utilizes ModelForm internally (eg, if you define model field as not nullable, serializer checks that). Still there are cases where you need modelform.

Answer (score 3):

Both of them refers to the same thing with a little bit difference.

Model fields are used within the database i.e while creating the schema, visible to the developer only.

while Serializer fields are used to when exposing the api to the client, visible to client also.